# ffmpeg creating gif from images, add watermark during creation?

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

I'm successfully creating animations from a series of static png's. I also want to add a watermark, but I'm having some issues when trying to add the watermark source.

Using this generates the animations fine:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -framerate 4 -i /tmp/img-%d.png -i /tmp/img-palette.png -lavfi "paletteuse" -y -loop 0 -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -hide_banner /tmp/output.mp4
```

When I add the following to specify the watermark source (transparent png) an error is generated:

```
-i /tmp/logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=(main_w-100):(main_h-50)"
```

Full command:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -framerate 4 -i /tmp/logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=(main_w-100):(main_h-50)" -i /tmp/img-%d.png -i /tmp/img-palette.png -lavfi "paletteuse" -y -loop 0 -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -hide_banner /tmp/output.mp4
```

Error:

```
video:1kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Do I need to generate the animation first, then apply the watermark to that artifact or is there a way to combine everything together during the creation process?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -v warning -framerate 4 -i /tmp/img-%d.png -i /tmp/img-palette.png -i /tmp/logo.png -filter_complex "[0][2]overlay=x=(main_w-100):(main_h-50)[v];[v][1]paletteuse" -y -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -hide_banner /tmp/output.mp4
```

Specify all inputs upfront. You can only specify one filter_complex. `-lavfi` is an alias for `filter_complex`.

Comment: Thanks @mulvya. Can you break down what's happening in "[0][2]overlay=x=(main_w-100):(main_h-50)[v];[v][1]paletteuse"?

Comment: `[0][2]overlay` --> overlay the 3rd input on the first. `..[v]` --> label this output `v`. `[v][1]` --> modify the overlay output using the 2nd input. Although I see you are generating a MP4, not GIF. You don't need a palette for that.

Comment: ok that makes sense. Yeah I left the palette bit in their because the same command gets used based on a user interface choice.